# Automatic forward a call

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I know that WP has a way to forward a call but I would like to build a app to manage that. So I have tried to check what APIs are available for the phone functions but I don't seem to find one regarding call forwarding?

So any help in pointing me in the right directions are appreciated!

Comment: The only phone apis that are available require user interaction.  You will not get a event fired when a call is received.  You do not have access to the call history either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs available to do this. (As far as I know not even the operator-only ones can pull this off.)